# select a single val though a table in wordpress

Tags: php, plugin-development, database, mysql, wpdb

The table is like this:

```
category_id   category_name   category_parent_name
```

I would like to get `category_id` by using `category_name`. I searched online, and the code is like below:

`$ad_cat` is the category name.

```
global $wpdb;
  $tbl_categories = $wpdb->prefix."awpcp_categories";
   $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM $tbl_categories where category_name =".$ad_cat );
$category_id=intval($retrieve_data->category_id);
```

I echo'ed category name and `id` for testing. The name shows fine, but `id` is always `0`.
Any idea or solution?

Comment: What is `var_dump($retrieve_data);` ?

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#483 (1) { ["category_name"]=> string(20) "Fitness and Exercise" } }  The fitness and exercise id should be 5

Comment: If you ran `SELECT *` on that table and only got `category_name` then your table does not look like you say it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the method `get_var()` instead. I've also tidied up your code (if you're gonna use double quotes, take advantage of them!) & added data escaping with the handy `prepare()` method.

```
global $wpdb;

$cat_id = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT category_id FROM {$wpdb->prefix}awpcp_categories WHERE category_name = %s",
        $ad_cat
    )
);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. I have question about the answer: what do mean when you say"take advantage of using double quotes...?"

Comment: Also, is there any different between get results and get var?

Comment: @Pluto [Check out the codex on `wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for a rundown of the different methods. PHP will interpret variables in [double quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3446286/247223), so no need to concatenate (join with dots).